# Create a selected sequence or inner class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, inner-classes

I want to create a selection sequence or create an Inner Class for each button to handle the event click of each of the buttons. My assignment is to click a button to display in a textbox or label the button that was clicked within the interface.

So far, I made six buttons and two panels (three buttons in each panel). I am still having a struggle with making an inner class. I am not sure how to use ActionListener and ActionPerformed. I need help with making inner class to display selected button in a textbox. THANKS!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PracticeEventDriven extends JFrame {

    public PracticeEventDriven()
    {
    JButton firstButton = new JButton("Button 1");
    JButton secondButton = new JButton("Button 2");
    JButton thirdButton = new JButton("Button 3");
    JButton fourthButton = new JButton("Button 4");
    JButton fifthButton = new JButton("Button 5");
    JButton sixthButton = new JButton("Button 6"); 

    /*Something is wrong with this. I want to use Button 4 to display.*/

    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener();
    fourthButton.addActionListener(listener);

        JPanel group1 = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        group1.add(firstButton);
        group1.add(secondButton);
        group1.add(thirdButton);        

        JPanel group2 = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        group2.add(fourthButton);
        group2.add(fifthButton);
        group2.add(sixthButton);

        this.getContentPane().add(group1);
        this.getContentPane().add(group2);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PracticeEventDriven frame = new PracticeEventDriven();
        frame.setTitle("Button Panel Example");
        frame.setSize(600, 85);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JButtonaddActionListenerActionListeneract.htm

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you need to use `ActionListener` on your buttons. Read tutorial about [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), and read [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html). I have changed yours code, examine it:

```
public class PracticeEventDriven extends JFrame {

    private JTextField field;

    public PracticeEventDriven() {
        field = new JTextField(10);
        JButton firstButton = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton secondButton = new JButton("Button 2");
        JButton thirdButton = new JButton("Button 3");
        JButton fourthButton = new JButton("Button 4");
        JButton fifthButton = new JButton("Button 5");
        JButton sixthButton = new JButton("Button 6");

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JButton b = (JButton) arg0.getSource();
                field.setText(b.getText());
            }
        };
        firstButton.addActionListener(listener);
        secondButton.addActionListener(listener);
        thirdButton.addActionListener(listener);
        fifthButton.addActionListener(listener);
        fourthButton.addActionListener(listener);
        sixthButton.addActionListener(listener);

        JPanel group1 = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        group1.add(firstButton);
        group1.add(secondButton);
        group1.add(thirdButton);

        JPanel group2 = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        group2.add(fourthButton);
        group2.add(fifthButton);
        group2.add(sixthButton);

        this.getContentPane().add(group1);
        this.getContentPane().add(group2);
        this.getContentPane().add(field);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PracticeEventDriven frame = new PracticeEventDriven();
        frame.setTitle("Button Panel Example");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```